# How to change the colour of bins in ggplot (geom_bin2d) to reflect difference between density in that area and the average density across a dataset?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, bins

Say I have some data that looks a bit like this

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

employee <- employee <- c('John','Dave','Paul','Ringo','George','Tom','Jim','Harry','Jamie','Adrian')
quality <- c('good', 'bad')
x = runif(4000,0,100)
y = runif(4000,0,100)
employ.data <- data.frame(employee, quality, x, y)
```

And I'm working with a geom_bin2d plot that looks like this

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_bin2d(binwidth = c(20, 20)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="darkred", high = "darkgreen")
```

￼[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p9n6.png)

How can I change the colour of the bins to reflect the percentage of the x/y points that are 'bad' compared to the overall average in that area across the dataset? I.e, if the average of 'bad' points in the bottom left bin is x number, and the average for John in that area is y lower number, how can I make the bin colour darker to show that his count is lower?

I figured this could work to create the averages:

```
df2 <-  employ.data
df2$xbin <- cut(df2$x, breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 20))
df2$ybin <- cut(df2$y, breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 20))
df2 <- df2 %>% group_by(xbin, ybin) %>% mutate(ave_pct = mean(quality == "bad"))
df2 <- df2 %>% group_by(employee, xbin, ybin) %>%  mutate(person_pct = mean(quality == "bad"))
```

But then I have no idea how to plot that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I am understanding you correctly, you would like to have the bins colored by how each respective bins percentage of bad employees compares to the overall percentage of bad employees. To accomplish this, I changed up how this was calculated to this:

```
df <- employ.data %>%
  mutate(xbin = cut(x, breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 20)),
         ybin = cut(y, breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 20)),
         overall_ave = mean(quality == "bad")) %>%
  group_by(xbin, ybin) %>%
  mutate(bin_ave = mean(quality == "bad")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(bin_quality = bin_ave - overall_ave)
```

This creates the bins, then finds the overall percentage of "bad" quality employees. Then it groups by the respective bins, and finds the percentage of "bad" employees per bin. Then it compares each bin average to the overall average. This gives a positive value  for `bin_quality` for bins with a higher percentage of "good" employees and a negative number for bins with a higher percentage of "bad" employees.

You can then graph it by adding a `fill = bin_quality` and `group = bin_quality` argument to your `aes()` call inside of `ggplot`. You also need to add `aes(group = bin_quality)` to your `geom_bin2d` call. It looks like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = bin_quality, group = bin_quality)) +
  geom_bin2d(aes(group = bin_quality), binwidth = c(20, 20)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="darkred", high = "darkgreen")
```

This gives you this graph:

[image]

Comment: This is absolutely perfect, thank you! You're a bloody star!

Comment: One more question: is it possible to filter out an option and retain the entire 'bin quality' range? Because otherwise it only focuses on the bin qualty associated with that employee.

Comment: You could add a `dplyr::filter` statement to the pipeline. I am not sure exactly what you want filtered so i can't give you the exact code.

Comment: I'm doing that already. What I mean is, when the data has been cut up and I'm filtering and plotting, say, "John", the plot is only taking into account the range of bin quality for John. And I want it to acknowledge the bin quality for everyone because, unless I'm mistaken, the fact that it is only 'seeing' the bin quality for John will affect the output.